# EPC light, no throttle, P2101 code

Tags: dtc, throttle-body, limp-home-mode

I've had an issue past few months where the EPC light turns on suddenly when I start the engine with code P2101. The throttle works but only up to 2k RPM and the car seems to be in some form of lim mode. The moment I turn the engine off and on again it works like normal and the check engine light goes off after a few drive cycles. When I return to the car and attempt to start it again I have the same issue. It seems to only happen when I start the car every now and then.

I did experience a weird problem a few weeks ago which has only happened to me once, while driving on the highway and attempting to accelerate from 50 to 60 mph or so the throttle stopped working completely and the EPC light came on again with the same trouble code. I had to coast to shoulder of the highway restart the engine and it worked like normal.

Could a dirty throttle body cause these issues?

For reference:

Car: 2004 Seat ibiza 6L

Engine code: BBY (NA 1,4 litre petrol)

Mileage: 110000 km (63000 miles)

Comment: While not familiar with Seats, EFI systems can be either complicated or relatively easy to understand, depending on diy knowledge. If your throttle body is electronically controlled (electronic pedal tells the ecm to command throttle - true drive by wire throttle), default software prevents a runaway engine with 'limp home' or reduced throttle, mode to allow driving at reduced speed. Your temporary solution is delaying eventual repairs. This may be as simple as a dirty throttle body needing cleaning or more (with little history given on maintenance).